# CSS @media print Print Preview Failed

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I was trying to make a change to hide a few unimportant things from print, and now my printing fails on all browsers (Chrome, FF, IE) and I'm not sure how to fix it.

This is a major issue and I looked at other similar questions and none of the fixes work for me.

I'd appreciate any help.

The issue can be seen at http://www.100candles.com/ -- Just go to any page and try to *Print Preview*

TIA!

Comment: What about it fails? Does it just fail to print or does it fail to even load the print preview?

Comment: I'm sorry, I found the issue.  it was a stupid thing but got me worried since the site is live.  I will close this question now.  any idea how I can close the question?  all I can do is `vote` to close it.